# Error while Passing structure to a function using reference

Tags: c++, structure, pass-by-reference

Trying to pass structure rectangle to function area to calculate it by call by reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int area(struct rectangle & r1)
{
    return r1.length*r1.width;
}

struct rectangle
{
    int length;
    int width;
};

int main()
{
    struct rectangle r={10,5};
    int total=area(r);
    std::cout << "Area is:" << total <<  std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, cut and paste the code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You just have your code in the wrong order, it should look like this

```
struct Rectangle
{
    ...
};

int area(Rectange& r1)
{
    ...
}
```

You must define `Rectangle` before you use it for the first time, not afterwards.